# How to loop through excel columns and print string in new column

Tags: vba, excel

My title might not be clear so I'll try to explain it with an example.

Let's say I have an excel sheet with one column for city names and another column for state names and a third column for country names.  I want to loop through the columns and in a 4th column print what was found in the other 3 columns.  So let's say column one is "Houston", column two is "Texas", and column three is "USA", how would I print to the fourth column "HTXUSA"?  I have almost no experience in VB in Excel so I'm hoping someone will be able to help.

I searched for similar topics but couldn't find anything that was helpful.  A couple threads helped a little bit, but I still don't have this figured out.

Comment: Do you have abbreviations like Houston => H, Texas => TX stored somewhere?

Comment: I do not.  It does come from a list of only 22 possibilities.  I used cities and states because it's easier to explain that.  I guess I would need a bunch of if statements to go through all of the options?

Comment: Well -- if you store your abbreviations as tables in Excel then your 4th column could be constructed using the built-in Excel functions `VLOOKUP` and `CONCATENATE` with no VBA at all. Also -- does your second column make sense in all cases? Not every country has states

Comment: I guess that was a bad example.  Given the actual case I need this for, everything will make sense.  If I wanted to use VBA, would you have any suggestions?

Comment: you will not get much VBA help if you do not show any of your own coding efforts to get what you want to get done. If you show your efforts, it will become much more clear what you want to do. Right now, it seems as if Excel formulas would suffice, and its always best to use Excel's built-in functions before using VBA.

Comment: I don't have any written code for this.  I don't know VBA very well so I don't know where this would start.  Once I know what the right approach is then I will most likely not have a problem with the coding.  I'll try using the built-in features and see if that works.

Comment: You better start with the tutorials found in the tag-wiki:http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, here is a VBA solution. It uses a public `Dictionary` object. These really come from VBScript but can be used in VBA in a couple of ways, including by `CreateObject`. The dictionary is initialized just once, the first time the corresponding `Abbreviate` function is called. This function takes a range, and for each cell in the range sees if there is a corresponding dictionary key. If so -- the corresponding value is concatenated onto the growing string, if not -- the value itself is. I am making keys upper case so as to make everything case-insensitive:

```
Public Abbreviations As Variant
Public Initialized As Boolean

Sub Initialize()
    Dim A As Variant, i As Long, n As Long
    'modify the following:
    A = Array("Houston", "H", "Dallas", "D", "Cleveland", "C", _
              "Toronto", "T", "Texas", "TX", "Ohio", "OH", _
              "Ontario", "ON", "Canada", "CAN")
    n = UBound(A) - 1
    Set Abbreviations = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 0 To n Step 2
        Abbreviations.Add UCase(A(i)), A(i + 1)
    Next i
    Initialized = True
End Sub

Function Abbreviate(R As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, s As String
    Dim cell As Range

    If Not Initialized Then Initialize
    For Each cell In R.Cells
        If Abbreviations.exists(UCase(cell)) Then
            s = s & Abbreviations(UCase(cell))
        Else
            s = s & UCase(cell)
        End If
    Next cell
    Abbreviate = s
End Function
```

A screenshot of how it works:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, you nailed it! Thank you so much.  I was looking for some direction, but you've done way more than I could have asked.  Thank you again.